# Removing '&title' from the URL in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create shorter urls to some of my pages.

Previously I had a system that URLs were like `/index.php?m=page&title=Page-Title`

The piece of code I have now allows me to remove the everything 'm=' part. `/index.php?m=page` in here, the 'page' is a name of different modules, so this part might still change. I want to change the url only from 'page'.

How would I rewrite this so that my URL would be composed only as such:

```
/page=Page-Title
```

Would that be even possible since I'm using `$_GET` in 2 places?

My current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page=([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=page&t=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm I can't get this to work with such url '/page=Page-Title' while older url work '/page&title=Page-Title'.

Comment: What is the URL you are entering in your browser and what should it be internally rewritten to?

Comment: I am typing 'page=Page-Title' as this is my aim.

Comment: ok what happens when open this URL: `http://domain.com/index.php?title=test-page=2` in your browser?

Comment: It sits on index as if 'p=page' was ommited.

Comment: Right but can you tell me long internal URL for `project.byethost6.com/page=test-page-2`?

Comment: index.php?p=page&t=Test-Page

Comment: Compact and efficient, +1 :)